# How to Display Value between html tags in Vb.net Form

Tags: regex, vb.net, webclient, vb.net-2010

I want to Extract number between font tags from a website in my vb.net form

```
<html> 
...
When asked enter the code: <font color=blue>24006 </font>
...
</html>
```

The 24006 is Auto generated number which Change automatically.

i use:

```
Dim str As String = New WebClient().DownloadString(("http://www.example.com"))
     Dim pattern = "When asked enter the code: <font color=blue>\d{5,}\s</font>"
        Dim r = New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Dim m As Match = r.Match(str)
        If m.Success Then
            Label1.Text = "Code" + m.Groups(1).ToString()
            m = m.NextMatch()

        Else
            Debug.Print("Failed")
        End If
```

But got Output in Label1:

Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the capturing group. Regex should be "`When asked enter the code: <font color=blue>(\d{5,})\s<\/font>`" (notice the parentheses around \d{5,}).

Regards